# How to build a population pyramid with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

How to  plot a population pyramid based on the following starting dataframe?

```py
           Age  Gender  Count
0  50-45 years    male      4
1  50-45 years  female      5
2  55-65 years    male      6
3  55-65 years  female      7
4  65-70 years    male     11
5  65-70 years  female     12
```

I tried the following, [Population Pyramid with Python and Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63619776/7758804), but the resulting plot looks strange:

```py
import pnadas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# data
data = {'Age': ['50-45 years', '50-45 years', '55-65 years', '55-65 years', '65-70 years', '65-70 years'],
        'Gender': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female'], 'Count': [4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Count', y='Age',
            hue='Gender', orient='horizontal', 
            dodge=False)
```

I think the problem is that my age is a string.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Unlike in the linked question, `'Count'` for both `'Gender'` groups is positive, so with `dodge=False`, the `'Female'` bars are drawn on top of the `'Male'` bars.
- Convert one of the groups to negative values, using `.loc` and Boolean selection.

```py
# convert male counts to negative
df.loc[df.Gender.eq('male'), 'Count'] = df.Count.mul(-1)

# plot
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Count', y='Age', hue='Gender', orient='horizontal', dodge=False)
```

[image]